# Use *sql* database for lab book data

Tags: python, sql, database, csv, pandas

I am currently keeping track of my wet work (lab work) by creating a `.csv` file for each iteration of an experiment type, and entering the substrate samples, resulting samples, and experiment variables in the columns; e.g. this is file `pcr_0055.csv` (here "DNA sample" is what goes in, and "ID" what comes out)

```
ID,    "thermocycler protocol", "pcr mix", "DNA sample", primers,         comment
TP2pj0, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      Tpbp2,       cre_fw5,
TP2pj1, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      Tpbp2,       "cre_fw5, cre_fw3",
TP2pj2, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      Tpbp2,       "cre_fw5, epcc_fw1",
TP2pj3, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      Tpbp3,       cre_fw5,
TP2pj4, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      Tpbp3,       "cre_fw5, cre_fw3",
TP2pj5, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      Tpbp3,       "cre_fw5, epcc_fw1",
TP2pj6, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      TP2ph8,      cre_fw5,
TP2pj7, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      TP2ph8,      "cre_fw5, cre_fw3",
TP2pj8, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      TP2ph8,      "cre_fw5, epcc_fw1",
TP2pj9, TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      TP2ph9,      cre_fw5,
TP2pj10,TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      TP2ph9,      "cre_fw5, cre_fw3",
TP2pj11,TP2T6,                  TP2M2,      TP2ph9,      "cre_fw5, epcc_fw1",
```

I am browsing through my files using `grep`, and the performance is acceptable.

I was thinking of maybe reorganizing my data so that each substance ID gets its own `.csv`, which should allow me to better keep track of the volume that is left me, etc. not to mention that the filename `pcr_0055.csv` is quite meaningless.

I was however also wondering, if I might actually be better served by migrating to a database model. I need an infrastructure that easily adapts to large data, can be searched rapidly, and provides me with the possibility to have lots of empty columns (if I am to list each procedure I perform on one sample, I will have different variables per procedure).

What I would like to know:

- Are databases something for my use case? And if not really, then with what reservations?
- What differences between MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc. should I be aware of in choosing an SQL/database implementation?
- Which of these (or other) database solutions integrates well (best?) with Python and Pandas?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages product recommendations.  So, I'll do it in a comment.  Your problem is quite amenable to databases, and you'll probably find more uses when you start using one.  You have a bona fide CSV format, so I would put Postgres near the top of the list.od

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I reformulated the question, so that I am not asking for a recommendation directly. Why would having a CSV format make PostgreSQL a better choice?

Comment: You can also look into using an ORM like SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 3):

The question is not really *what* database, but *how you will use* the database. You use a very important word **infrastructure**.

Among Relational Database Management Systems, there are essentially two structural types:

- file-level databases which includes popular forms such as MS Access
  and SQLite (open-source);
- server-level databases which includes SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL
  (open-source), PostgreSQL (open-source), and DB2, among still others.

Rest assured all the aforementioned SQL engines work great with Python as they do with PHP, R, and statistical packages like SAS. See this great SQLite tutorial on [appropriate database uses](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

How to pick the most optimal type depends on *how* you want to manage your Lab data. Many will agree if you are not designing for an enterprise solution (i.e., hundreds of transactions/users/GBs), client servers systems like PostgreSQL may be overkill. A few questions to consider:

1. How much data do you expect to handle? Will lab data involve numerous related tables (i.e., many splits of SubstanceID)? Data size of a few hundred MB? GB? TB? File servers are usually lower key alternatives, but still powerful.
2. Do you have a relational model and design schema to set up the database architecture for indexing and other best practices?
3. Are you prepared to install and handle auxiliary components (i.e., ODBC drivers,  and manage services like SQL Server Browser, MySQL Services, possibly Apache)?
4. Do you require remote connections and accesses? Are you prepared to manage security for such server level?
5. Do you expect many multiple users to connect and run action queries?
6. Will there be many file conversion processing (csv, tsv, txt, xml, xlsx, etc.)? MS Access for instance leverages the Office Suite and can handle natively many file types from CSVs to Excel spreadsheets to XML.
7. Do you have the necessary RAM, hard disk, etc. to scale such database solutions? No doubt all the aforementioned can work off a laptop but server level RDMSs work optimally across LAN and web networks.

Admittedly, I might be overthinking your process but to really set up an optimal database solution should take careful decision-making. You would hate to put time and resources in an infrastructure that does not work for your everyday needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Databases are a great tool for this job, you have well defined structured data and relationships between data layers.
2. Gordon recommended PostgreSQL because it's free and has easy to use syntax for importing data directly from CSVs into tables.
3. MySQL, PostgreSQL both integrate with python very well, I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a remotely well known DBMS platform that doesn't integrate with Python.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You are using CSV format in its full-fledged form -- with support for commas in fields.  In my experience, SQL Server does not handle this format well.  I don't think Oracle does either.  In those cases, I read the file into Excel and save it out in a tab-delimited format.

Postgres, on the other hand, supports the full CSV conventions, including escaped fields.  I'm not sure if MySQL does.